# How to manually create future which will block in destructor

Tags: c++, future

I've read http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2013/03/stdfutures-from-stdasync-arent-special.html but it doesn't show an example of how one can implement the same kind of behavior - i.e. a future that will block in destructor same as the one returned from async but without using any async.

Can you please give such an example? Thanks!

Comment: why not wrap a normal std::future in a struct with a call to .get in the destructor?

Comment: I just want to understand how can it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the comment thread underneath that article, you would see that other experts do not agree:

- That `future`s which are not from `async` should block in the destructor.
- With Scott Meyers interpretation of the standard that it should be the case.

Martinho Fernandes:

> I don't see why this is a requirement for all futures: **this particular requirement you quote is from the requirements upon `std::async`, not the requirements on `std::future`.** The only requirement on the destructor of `std::future` is that it "releases the shared state". It happens that the shared state from `std::async` adds the requirement you quote, but no other shared state in the standard library has such a requirement.

Herb Sutter:

> tl;dr: Martinjo already answered this correctly -- the article is not correct, the blocking applies only to futures returned from `std::async` with launch policy `launch::async`.
>
> > Scott said: 
> >     and in 30.6.8/5, we see that [...] This is a requirement for any future object, not just the ones returned from `std::async` calls.
>
> This does not follow. 30.6.8 is the specification of `std::async`. **Anything said in there is specific to `std::async`.**
>
> But as Martinho already correctly said, this exception is in clause 30.6.8 "Function template async" only, **and does not apply to futures in general.**

**Conclusion:** I do not think you will be able to find the example you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Am I correct than that to implement similar behavior I would have to create smth like the folowing

`struct SharedState {~SharedState() { thread th()[] { while (true); }); th.join(); } };` and the use it in future as `future<SharedState> f;`?

Comment: @xor256: Not sure what you are trying to do. But the code as you have given will not compile.

Comment: This is a pseudocode. ;) I'm trying to understand how can async implement a future that will block in destructor. Since it is shared state which is actually released I've assumed that the only way it can do it is to create a future with a SharedState which will wait in destructor for a thread (in an example infinitely). So I was trying to come up with an example where SharedState in destructor creates a thread which never finishes an joins it -> such future IIUC when returned from a function will block in destructor.

Comment: @xor256: Implementation of async: You can read this question and answers for more info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673475/how-is-stdasync-implemented. Some interesting info about async and future from this paper from Herb Sutter. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3630.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link! Still I don't see an answer to my question there. So I've made up an example which compiles: https://pastebin.com/NDhuUHbu. Is this somewhat similar to async implementation?

Comment: Different compilers do it differently. For GCC you can check this out: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00879.html

Comment: Thanks. This really looks similar `~_Async_state() { _M_thread.join(); }`

Comment: @xor256: You are welcome. I hope this means your question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering to myself, but just to confirm that the question is answered: as per https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00879_source.html it is indeed the shared state destructor that blocks not the future itself.

```
  template<typename _Res>
     class __future_base::_Async_state : public __future_base::_State
     {
     public:
       typedef _Res _Res_type;

       explicit 
       _Async_state(std::function<_Res()>&& __fn)
       : _M_result(new _Result<_Res>()), _M_fn(std::move(__fn)),
     _M_thread(mem_fn(&_Async_state::_M_do_run), this)
       { }

       ~_Async_state() { _M_thread.join(); }
```

And the future returned from async happens to use this exact kind of state. The same behavior can be achieved by creating a class which destructor will join() on some thread and creating a future with this class as template parameter: https://ideone.com/5RAPoA