# Using c++11's std::async inside an abstract base class

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stdthread, stdasync, std-future

Why doesn't making threads like this work inside of an abstract base class? I'm trying to abstract away all of the multithreading details for users who derive from this base class.  I don't understand why it says "no type named 'type'" when I clearly write that `callbackSquare` returns type `int`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

class ABC{
public:
    std::vector<std::future<int> > m_results;
    ABC(){};
    ~ABC(){};
    virtual int callbackSquare(int& a) = 0;
    void doStuffWithCallBack();
};

void ABC::doStuffWithCallBack(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        m_results.push_back(std::async(&ABC::callbackSquare, this, i));

    for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        std::cout << m_results[j].get() << "\n";
}

class Derived : public ABC {
    Derived() : ABC() {};
    ~Derived(){};
    int callbackSquare(int& a) {return a * a;};
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    std::cout << "testing\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The strange errors I'm getting are:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/future:1709:67:   required from 'std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = int (ABC::*)(int&); _Args = {ABC*, int&}; typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type = int]'
/usr/include/c++/5/future:1725:19:   required from 'std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = int (ABC::*)(int&); _Args = {ABC*, int&}; typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type = int]'
/home/taylor/Documents/ssmworkspace/callbacktest/main.cpp:16:69:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1505:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<int (ABC::*)(int&)>(ABC*, int)>'
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1526:9: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<int (ABC::*)(int&)>(ABC*, int)>'
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

Comment: "`callbackSquare(int& a)`" is there a reason for the pass by ref?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to std::async by reference fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359864/passing-arguments-to-stdasync-by-reference-fails)

Comment: @curiousguy not really for this example. But eventually I'll be passing arguments that are larger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem can be reproduced with any function that accepts a reference:

```
#include <future>

int f(int& a)
{
    return a * a;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    auto r = std::async(f, i);
}
```

Accepting a reference in your code is risky since the variable *will be modified* by the loop iteration, creating a data race because the called function also accesses the variable.

Change the function to accept the input parameter by value, or call `std::async` by passing `std::ref(i)` or `std::cref(i)` (in case the function accepts a const reference) if you acknowledge the risk.