# error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::launch(bool (*)(diffpng::CompareArgs&), diffpng::CompareArgs)>’

Tags: c++

my code is like:

```
    std::vector<bool> LevelClimberCompareMulti(std::vector<CompareArgs> &args) {
    std::vector<bool> ret(args.size());
    std::vector<std::shared_future<bool>> fts(args.size());
    //using ArgIter = std::vector<CompareArgs>::iterator;
    //using FtIter = std::vector<std::shared_future<bool>>::iterator;
    std::transform(args.begin(), args.end(), fts.begin(),
            [](CompareArgs& a) -> std::shared_future<bool> {return std::async(std::launch::async, &diffpng::LevelClimberCompare, a).share();});
    std::transform(fts.begin(), fts.end(), ret.begin(),
            [](std::shared_future<bool> ft) -> bool {return ft.get();});
    return ret;
}
```

example:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>

using CompareArgs = int;

namespace diffpng {
    bool LevelClimberCompare(CompareArgs &args) {
        return true;
    }

    std::vector<bool> LevelClimberCompareMulti(std::vector<CompareArgs> &args) {
        std::vector<bool> ret(args.size());
        std::vector<std::shared_future<bool>> fts(args.size());
        //using ArgIter = std::vector<CompareArgs>::iterator;
        //using FtIter = std::vector<std::shared_future<bool>>::iterator;
        std::transform(args.begin(), args.end(), fts.begin(),
                [](CompareArgs& a) -> std::shared_future<bool> {return std::async(std::launch::async, &diffpng::LevelClimberCompare, a).share();});
        std::transform(fts.begin(), fts.end(), ret.begin(),
                [](std::shared_future<bool> ft) -> bool {return ft.get();});
        return ret;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<CompareArgs> args{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto res = diffpng::LevelClimberCompareMulti(args);
    for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "res[" << i << "]: " << res[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I get errors like that:
I wonder what the error is about and how can I fix it up?
btw, I am currently run it on a Win10 WSL ubuntu shell, but I dont think that has something to do with the error here.
gcc version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

compile it simply with the cmd: `g++ -std=c++14 example.cpp` you can see the error.

[image]

Comment: Is `diffpng::LevelClimberCompare` a static function or a non static function?

Comment: Beware `std::vector<bool>` - it is not a `std::vector` and it does not contain `bool`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and your errors as text not an image

Comment: it's a non-static function under the same namespace @NathanOliver

Comment: added @AlanBirtles

Comment: thanks, but I dont think the problem is on that level @Eugene

Comment: I dont get it @ThomasSablik

Comment: Did you read the link?

Comment: anybody plz help me? this should be a tiny problem on some subtle grammar problems. I haven't written cpp for a period of time and I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I have posted a example and it's can not run. I've work on this piece of code for about an hour to make sure no newbee problem.

Comment: Read the link or accept the downvotes and the closed question.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I've read the link and I've posted the minimal reproducible example. have you seen that?

Comment: The link doesn't mention an example. I'm pretty you didn't read it.

Comment: I dont get it. what I'm doing has nothing to do with posting error stack, there is no stacking. I cant even compile it now...... what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments in `std::async` are passed as temporary copies (rvalues). You can't assign an rvalue to a reference. To fix your problem you could use const ref or copy

```
bool LevelClimberCompare(const CompareArgs &args)
```

or

```
bool LevelClimberCompare(CompareArgs args)
```

You can use `std::ref` or `std::cref` to pass a reference

```
std::async(std::launch::async, &diffpng::LevelClimberCompare, std::ref(a))
```

Comment: exactly! I have known that it must be some trivial error. but I didn't see that would be the result. Btw, I have tried the clang, and it also gives me an error like the gcc and confusion it might cause.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18360675/5978133 has a better explanation of this topic.