# Address of reference variable is different when function is called using std::async

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++17

In the following snippet of code, the address of `v` in `print` function is same as address of `a` when
`std::ref(a)` is used in `std::async`, but different when `a` is passed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

void print (const int& v)
{
    std::cout  << "&v = " << &v << "\n";
}


int main()
{
    int a = 10;

    auto f = std::async(print, std::ref(a));
    f.get();
    
    std::cout  << "&a = " << &a << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

output

```
&v = 0x7ffd3b5000b4
&a = 0x7ffd3b5000b4
```

But when I remove `std::ref` then address is different

```
auto f = std::async(print, a);
```

output

```
&v = 0x55586497cef8
&a = 0x7ffee2e3dadc
```

**Question:**

- Do `std::async` copies the data rather than reference if `std::ref` is not used ?
- why addresses is changes even though my `print` function parameter is reference type `const int &`

Reference: [Passing arguments to std::async by reference fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359864/passing-arguments-to-stdasync-by-reference-fails)

Comment: Yes, `async` copies/moves args by default. Same as `std::thread` constructor.

Comment: so if I a remove `const` from `void print (const int& v)` and make it as `void print (int& v)` then compiler is forcing me to use `std::ref` while passing argument. That means now it takes reference rather than copy/move ? Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, `std::ref` forces a reference to be passed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that means calling `print` from `std::async` is thread safe since it has a copy of my variable in it right ?

Comment: If you remove `ref`, yes.

Comment: Thanks and how to accept your answer?

Comment: You can't accept comments, only answers. And I don't want to post a full answer, because I feel this is already explained in the thread you linked.