# Using std::async with a method receiving a cv::OutputArray in order to assign it doesn't work

Tags: c++, opencv, concurrency, future, stdasync

I have the following function:

```c++
void MyClass::myFunc(cv::OutputArray dst) const {
    cv::Mat result;
    ...
    dst.assign(result);
}
```

If I run it like this:

```c++
cv::Mat result;
myFunc(result);
otherFunc(result);
```

It works fine and `otherFunc` recieves `result` modified by `myFunc`.

But if I use `std::async` like this:

```c++
cv::Mat result;
auto resultFuture = std::async(&MyClass::myFunc, this, result);
resultFuture.wait();
otherFunc(result);
```

`otherFunc` receives empty `result`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The root cause** is that passing arguments by reference (&) to a function to run via [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) is problematic. You can read about it here: [Passing arguments to std::async by reference fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359864/passing-arguments-to-stdasync-by-reference-fails) (in your case there is no a compilation error, but the link explains the issue in general).

And in your case you use `cv::OutputArray` which is defined in opencv as a refernce type:

```
typedef const _OutputArray& OutputArray;
```

I assume you wanted the reference semantics, since you expected your `result` object to be updated by `myFunc`.

**The solution is to use** `std::ref`.
But since the `result` object you pass is a `cv::Mat`, it preferable and more straightforward that `myFunc` will receive a `cv::Mat&`.
I also managed to produce a solution using a `cv::OutputArray`, but it requires an ugly cast (in addition to the `std::ref`). It works fine on MSVC, but I am not sure it is will be generally valid.

Below is the code demostrating these 2 options. I recomend to use the 1st approach if you can. You can call `otherFunc(result);` at the point where I print the dimensions of `result` after it is initialized.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

// Test using a cv::Mat &:
class MyClass1
{
    void myFunc(cv::Mat & dst) const
    {
        cv::Mat result(4, 3, CV_8UC1);
        result = 1; // ... initialize some values
        dst = result;   // instead of using cv::OutputArray::assign
    }
public:
    void test()
    {
        cv::Mat result;
        std::cout << "MyClass1: before: " << result.cols << " x " << result.rows << std::endl;
        auto resultFuture = std::async(&MyClass1::myFunc, this, std::ref(result));
        resultFuture.wait();
        // Here result will be properly set.
        std::cout << "MyClass1: after: " << result.cols << " x " << result.rows << std::endl;
    }
};

// Test using a cv::OutputArray:
class MyClass2
{
    void myFunc(cv::OutputArray dst) const
    {
        cv::Mat result(4, 3, CV_8UC1); 
        result = 1; // ... initialize some values
        dst.assign(result);
    }
public:
    void test()
    {
        cv::Mat result;
        std::cout << "MyClass2: before: " << result.cols << " x " << result.rows << std::endl;
        auto resultFuture = std::async(&MyClass2::myFunc, this, std::ref(static_cast<cv::OutputArray>(result)));
        resultFuture.wait();
        // Here result will be properly set.
        std::cout << "MyClass2: after: " << result.cols << " x " << result.rows << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Test receiving a cv::Mat&:
    MyClass1 m1;
    m1.test();
    // Test receiving a cv::OutputArray:
    MyClass2 m2;
    m2.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks for such a detailed answer!